# iOS crash : [__NSArrayM allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x178754d0

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

A user got this crash `[__NSArrayM allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x178754d0`
This is where the crash occurred.

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [[array allKeys] sortedArrayUsingFunction:sort context:nil];
```

I am not sure how this can occur. Any tips or suggestions on how to prevent this will be appreciated.

Edit:
This is my array, I should change the variable name.

```
id array = [parse objectWithString:answer];
```

Comment: A dictionary has keys, not an array.

Comment: Changing the name does not help, the object you are calling `allKeys` on is an array. You need to be clear on what you are parsing. Probably it is an array of one item a dictionary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What instance type is `array`? NSArray has no `allKeys` message that it can send, thus the unrecognized selector. You are treating `array` most likely as an `NSDictionary`.

Answer (score 2):

allKeys function is of NSDictionary not NSArray or NSMutableArray.
You should call this on NSDictionary instances.